# Ajax at home server web page

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache

1. I have **Apache** set on my home pc.

   1. A page called **ajax.html** has xmlhttp request set on a button. (for fetching a html page **main.html** residing in same directory)
   2. Whenever i click on button, nothing happens, i have set response as text.
   3. Below is javascript code.

   ```
   function()

   {    var httpRequest;    document.getElementById("ajaxButton").onclick = function() { makeRequest('main.html');  };
   ```

   function makeRequest(url) { 
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
         httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
       } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
         try { 
           httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
         }
         catch (e) { 
           try { 
             httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
           }
           catch (e) {} 
         } 
       }

   if (!httpRequest) { 
         alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance'); 
         return false; 
       } 
       httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents; 
       httpRequest.open('GET', url); 
       httpRequest.send();    }

   function alertContents() { 
       if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { 
         if (httpRequest.status === 200) { 
           alert(httpRequest.responseText); 
         } else { 
           alert('There was a problem with the request.'); 
         } 
       }    }  })();

html code;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="ajaxButton" value="Click" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console? If you are going to work with Ajax I would strongly recommend using a library like jQuery, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Are you running this from localhost or via `file://` url?

Comment: Chevi : I am starting to learn Ajax. So want to start with just bare bones of it.
@Sirko : Yes at localhost i have folder name web where this files are residing.

Comment: Can you share the page url and ajax resource url? It could be because of same origin policy http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Comment: url of ajax.html = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\ajax.html"
url of (resource page) main.html = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\main.html"
ip address in numeric is same, in both case.

Comment: using error console i could eliminate some syntax errors and now I am getting source code of requested web page in form of text on a pop up box.

Comment: Thanks to suggestion of @Chevi : error console provided some clues, which helped me to eliminate some syntax/indent related problems in JavaScript, and I made successful ajax call to web page on my localhost.

Comment: @msinfo great to hear that!